# Find Rightmost unset bit of a very large number

Tags: c++, bit

How to obtain rightmost unset bit position of a number N in c++.

1<= N <= 2^60

storing as number does not work since 2^60 can only be stored in string.
thus following does not work

```
long long getBitUtil(long long n) { 
    return log2(n&-n)+1; 
} 

long long getBit(long long n) { 
    return getBitUtil(~n);         
}
```

Comment: How is your very large number (integer?) represented? Do you have an example?

Comment: `2^60` will very well fit in `std::int64_t` or `std::uint64_t` - [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)

Comment: Please don't use macros or type-aliases of standard native types unless there's a specific semantic meaning behind them. Using it for shortening e.g. `long long` actually makes your code less readable, understandable and maintainable.

Comment: I think `long long` has to be at least 64 bits wide, so 2^60 has to fit in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Code is self explanatory with comments

```
int getRightmostUnSetBit(string s, int pos)
{
    int l= s.size();
    int lc = s[l-1];
    if(lc>=48 && lc<=57 && lc%2 ==0)
        return pos; // if last digit is even return position
    else
    {// divide the number into half and call function again.
        string s2 = "";
        int rem =0;
        for(int i =0; i<l;i++)
        {
            int d = s[i]-'0';
            d = rem *10 + d;
            int q = d/2;
            rem = d%2;
            s2.push_back('0'+q);
        }
        return getRightmostUnSetBit(s2,pos+1); //call for s2
    }
}
```

Take input in string and call  from main

```
int pos = getRightmostUnSetBit(s,1);// will not work if s is "0" or similar to "000...". So check for it before function calling.
```

Comment: Does not compile. I guess we need to substitute "fun" by "getRightmostSetBit" I corrected the code and tested. Does not deliver expected result. Did you test?

Comment: @ArminMontigny  I corrected it. Please check again.

Comment: I can compile, but I am still getting the wrong result. Please compare with my answer below. I guess that I do not use your function correctly.

Comment: @ArminMontigny, Please check now. I was finding rightmost set bit earlier. Now, I am finding unset bit

Comment: Very good. Now it works. Basically you are using the same algorithm as mine. You just terminate the loop, when you have found the first 0. So, regarding the asked question it is more efficient and hence +1 upvote

Answer (score 0):

For normal integers the solution is basically given in the book [Hackers Delight](https://www.amazon.de/Hackers-Delight-Henry-S-Warren/dp/0321842685/ref=sr_1_1?adgrpid=79470172228&gclid=CjwKCAjwmtDpBRAQEiwAC6lm4zeXFfnAB-wAOtjOB_Mmrp-RbGGK7qLo7N83pm_6Go2JFwRHvC1V9xoCBtoQAvD_BwE&hvadid=352639770182&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=1004337&hvnetw=g&hvpos=1t1&hvqmt=e&hvrand=12694556668465929191&hvtargid=kwd-299942660774&hydadcr=3704_1736395&keywords=hackers%20delight&qid=1563719559&s=gateway&sr=8-1). I can only refer to the book. I cannot copy. But section 2.1 gives already good hints.

Depending on your OS you will most likely have 64 bit data types. With 64 bit data types, you can still use arithmentic solutions for your given number range. Above that, you should use string representations.

Then we will convert a big decimal number given as string into a string containing its binary equivalent.

Then we search for the last 0 in the resulting binary string.

The secret is to do a division by 2 for a number given as string. This can be done as we learned in school on a piece of paper.

And then check, if the number is even or odd and put a 1 or 0 respectively in the resulting string.

This will work for abitrary big numbers. Limiting factor (but here not really) is the length of the resulting binary string. That must fit into a `std::string` :-)

See:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <stack>
#include <algorithm>

// Odd numbers. We will find out, if a digit is odd or even
std::string oddNumbers{ "13579" };

// Devide a number in a string by 2. Just like in school on a piece of paper
void divideDecimalNumberAsStringBy2(std::string& str)
{
    // Handling of overflow during devisions
    unsigned int nextNumberToAdd{ 0 };
    // The resulting new string
    std::string newString{};
    // Go through all digits, starting from the beginning
    for (char& c : str) {
        // Get overflow for next round
        unsigned int numberToAdd = nextNumberToAdd;
        // Get the overflow value for the next devision run. If number is odd, it will be 5
        nextNumberToAdd = (oddNumbers.find(c) != std::string::npos) ? 5 : 0;
        // Do the devision. Add overflow from last round
        unsigned int newDigit = (c - '0') / 2 + numberToAdd;
        // Build up newe string
        newString += static_cast<char>(newDigit + '0');
    }
    // Remove leading zeroes
    str = std::regex_replace(newString, std::regex("^0+"), "");
}

// Convert a string with a big decimal number to a string with a binar representation of the number
std::string convertDecimalStringToBinaryString(std::string& str)
{
    // Resulting string
    std::string binaryDigits{};
    // Until the string is empty. Will be shorter and short because of devision by 2
    while (!str.empty()) {
        // For an even number we add 0, for an odd number we add 1
        binaryDigits += (oddNumbers.find(str.back()) == std::string::npos) ? '0' : '1';
        // And devide by 2
        divideDecimalNumberAsStringBy2(str);
    }
    // Bits come in wrong order, so we need to revers it
    std::reverse(binaryDigits.begin(), binaryDigits.end());
    return binaryDigits;
}

int main()
{
    // Initial string with a big number. Get input from user
    std::string bigNumber{};
    std::cout << "Enter big number: ";
    std::cin >> bigNumber;

    // Convert it
    std::string binaryDigits = convertDecimalStringToBinaryString(bigNumber);
    
    // Find the last 0
    unsigned int posOfLast0 = binaryDigits.rfind('0');

    // Show result
    if (posOfLast0 == std::string::npos) 
        std::cout  << "\nNo digit is 0 --> " << binaryDigits << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "\nSize of resulting string: "<< binaryDigits.size() <<  "\nPos of last 0: " << posOfLast0+1  << "\nBinary String:\n\n" << binaryDigits << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```